# Issue using protobuf.util.JsonFormat in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, protocol-buffers

I successfully configured my project in Android Studio to generate the Java class for a protobuf and use it in my Java code. However, when trying the Json printer (in protobuf.util.JsonFormat) I get this:

*error: incompatible types: Person cannot be converted to MessageOrBuilder*

My code looks like:

```
Person      msg = Person.newBuilder().setName("A name").build();
Printer pp = JsonFormat.printer().preservingProtoFieldNames();
String val = pp.print(msg);
```

where Person is defined in the proto file. And the error is on the last line.

I tried to cast msg, but without success. I also try to not use lite but regular protobuf but I was not successful at compiling with it (and I am not sure if this would make a difference so I did not pursue).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use protobuf-lite with the JsonFormat printer. In my project I removed option:lite from my protobuf settings then it compiled